# if condition not working with || operator

Tags: java, xml

I have written java code to fetch a node from xml tag and based on the node ,it should be deleted.Its working fine for certain cases for the same condition  and its not working for certain cases.I have been trying to find a solution but unable to. Plz help me guys.Below is the Code I have written

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class CL_RGTIS_CREMAS_DWM_FILT {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CL_RGTIS_CREMAS_DWM_FILT domParse=new CL_RGTIS_CREMAS_DWM_FILT();
        try
        {
        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Home/Downloads/Test1.xml");        
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Home/Downloads/out.xml");
        domParse.execute(in,out);   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("catch exception"+e.getMessage());

        }

    }
    public void execute(FileInputStream in,FileOutputStream out)
    {
        try
        {
            TransformerFactory  transformerFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer=transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            //ignore whitespace within document
            factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
            /*parser is aware of name space*/
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            DocumentBuilder builderel=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document  docIn=builderel.parse(in);
            Node root, headerItem = null,childItem=null,childItem1=null;
            NodeList id, headerNodes = null,childNodes=null,childNodes1=null;

            id = docIn.getElementsByTagName("IDOC");
            for (int g =0; g< id.getLength(); g++)
            {

                root = id.item(g);          
                headerNodes = root.getChildNodes();


                for(int j =0; j<headerNodes.getLength(); j++)
                {   
                    headerItem = headerNodes.item(j);
                    childNodes=headerItem.getChildNodes();

                    for(int k=0;k<childNodes.getLength();k++)
                    {
                        childItem=childNodes.item(k);
                        childNodes1=childItem.getChildNodes();


                        if((childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("E1LFB1M"))||(childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("E1LFBKM")))
                        {
                            childItem.getParentNode().removeChild(childItem);
                            System.out.println("in if stmt");



                        }

                    }



                }

            }
            DOMSource dom = new DOMSource(docIn);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
            transformer.transform(dom, result);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("execute method"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain `working fine for certain cases for the same condition and its not working for certain cases`. What are these cases?

Comment: Nothing appears wrong with the `if` statement. It'll remove any nodes 3 layers down with those names.

Comment: We need more information in order to be able to help you. What cases does it work for? What cases does it not work for? Inputs and outputs make it easier to see what you are talking about

Comment: you can just write :`(childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("E1LFB1M")||childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("E1LFBKM"))` instead of ((childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("E1LFB1M"))||(childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("E1LFBKM"))). But i don't understand the cases that not work!!

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help you.  **However**, one thing you **may** be doing wrong is this: if you're using integer indexes to get items from a list (such as `childNodes.item(k)`), and you remove an item, the indexes of all the remaining items will shift down, and your code needs to adjust for that so that you don't miss an item when stepping through them.

Answer (score 0):

In the k-loop the code removes the k<sup>th</sup> childItem. I haven't the faintest idea, whether the NodeList is backed by the actual DOM node. You might try decrementing k, so you do not inadvertently skip the next item on the for's `k++`.

In every case `k < childNodes.getLength()` will iterate one less, when k is decremented.

```
         childItem.getParentNode().removeChild(childItem);
         --k;
```

Of course a more portable, safe solution should be better; collecting inside the loop a list of items to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if there are 6 tags with E1LfBKM tag then the only 4 times it is coming in the if block and the rest of the 2 are ignored.But actually it should go into the if statement 6 times.This is what I meant when I said cases.